# NJ EZ Pass Toll Violation

Tags: business

NJ EZ Pass claims that a vehicle registered to me violated a toll. The vehicle is neither mine, nor is it registered to me. I mailed my dispute with a copy of my registration of the vehicle I own.

NJ EZ Pass replied stating that my dispute required documentation from the DMV regarding all the vehicles registered to me for the past 5 years. I sent them this documentation of vehicles I've had registered to me for the past 15 yrs (which had the raised seal of the DMV) through certified mail so that I would get the receipt of delivery.

I just got ANOTHER notification about the original violation of this vehicle which is not registered to me, but which they insist is.

I would appreciate any guidance with this situation. The phone numbers on the website are automated only.

Comment: Ask them for the proof of ownership they are using to pursue their claim - once you have that, you can refute their evidence.  Or correct it.  The problem is, right now they are asking you to prove a negative, and thats almost impossible - how can you prove you have never owned something? There is no legal paperwork saying you dont own something until you have owned it and then given up ownership...  Proving you have owned other vehicles doesn't count, you need to prove you didn't own that vehicle, and the only way to do that is to refute the evidence of ownership they are using against you.

Comment: I actually got a human on the phone at the customer service office at Newark, NJ, and they agreed to dismiss the violation. At first, they wanted me to go back to the DMV to get proof that a vehicle with temporary plates has never been registered to me. I told them that it would have shown up on the report I sent them. After waiting on the phone, the supervisor agreed that no more violation notices would be sent to my home and that the violation is dismissed. What a relief!

Answer (score 1):

At some point, you will get a court date if you do not pay it.

If they will not accept your mailed documents, either take it to court yourself or show the judge the paperwork you have when you do go to court.

If it is really not you, the court will dismiss it.

Comment: They'd have a hard time taking EZ Pass to court, given there are no damages for them to claim. They'd have to wait for a court summons, if EZ Pass ever opts to do that.